# If $a, b, c ∈ \Bbb{N}$, then at least one of $a-b$, $a+c$, and $b-c$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This one has been frustrating me for a while. I need to find out whether the statement is true or not true and prove it. I think it's probably true, because it came out to be for every real number combination I tested.

The only way I've come up with proving this is to assume that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are either even or odd, and show that at least one of $a-b$, $a+c$, and $b-c$ is even. The issue is there are a lot of cases for me to prove, with $a$, $b$, or $c$ being either odd or even.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Assume $a-b$ and $a+c$ are both odd. Then, their sum $2a-b+c$ must be even, so $-b+c$ must be even and hence $b-c$ is even.

If our assumption is wrong, then there is nothing to prove, since one of them is already even.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possibilities for a natural number's parity: even or odd.

Since there are three integers $a,b$ and $c$, by the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), at least two of them must have the same parity.

If they have the same parity, their sum and their difference is even.

Answer (score 1):

Let all of them be odd. Then $(a-b)+(b-c)=a-c$ is even. Hence $a+c$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by [reduction to the absurd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum): If not even one of them is even, then all three are odd. In which case, their sum must be odd as well. But $(a-b)+(a+c)+(b-c)=2a$ is even: Contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

Reducing modulo$~2$, one has $\bar a+\bar c=\bar a-\bar c=(\bar a-\bar b)+(\bar b-\bar c)$. If both parenthesised expressions are $\bar 1$ (i.e., $a-b$ and $b-c$ are odd) then their sum is $\bar 0$ and $a+c$ is even.